# Using AJAX in WebSite Razor 3

Tags: vb.net, razor, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

I am programming a website in VS2013 in VBHTML (Razor 3).
This site does not use MVC.
I'm looking for documentation to use AJAX, but I only find information using MVC.
Does anyone know if it is possible to use AJAX without MVC????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use AJAX in a non-MVC web application.

The below link should help get you started.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691298/Creating-AJAX-enabled-web-forms

"Beginning ASP.NET 4.5.1 in C# and VB" by Imar Spannjaars walks you thru creating a website (not using Web Matrix) and chapter 13 is all about ASP.NET AJAX.  This book uses websites instead of web applications and does not cover any MVC.

Also the book "Professional ASP.NET 4.5 in C# and VB" is also a good resource.
This book focuses on developing applications using webforms.
[https://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-4-5-C-VB/dp/1118311825/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1498491649&sr=8-2&keywords=ASP.NET+4.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118311825)

Hopefully this will help you out.

Best regards,

Joe